# Nodejs multer options don't fire

Tags: node.js, multer

I'm trying to save files with multer but it doesn't really want to work :

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './')
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage,
onFileUploadComplete : function (file) {
    console.log('Completed file!');
},
onParseStart : function() {
     console.log('whatevs');
}});

app.post('/upload' ,upload.single('thisisme'), function(req,res) {});
```

The file does get saved, but ParseStart or UploadComplete are never fired. Why is that? I also tried using the app.use ( multer ... );

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because You are trying to use old multer api. In current version there is no event handlers: `onFileUploadComplete` and `onParseStart`. Please check documentation for api details : https://github.com/expressjs/multer

this part of Your code looks ok:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './')
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});
```

and this is also ok:

```
app.post('/upload' ,upload.single('thisisme'), function(req,res) {});
```

this is wrong:

```
var upload = multer({ storage: storage,
onFileUploadComplete : function (file) {
    console.log('Completed file!');
},
onParseStart : function() {
     console.log('whatevs');
}});
```

change it to this:

```
var upload = multer({ 
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter:function(req, file, cb) {
    //Set this to a function to control which files should be uploaded and which should be skipped. It is instead of onParseStart.
  }
});
```

There is nothing instead of `onFileUploadComplete`. But:

```
app.post('/upload' ,upload.single('thisisme'), function(req,res) {
//this is call when upload success or failed
});
```

you can change It to this:

```
app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
  upload.single('thisisme')(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      // An error occurred when uploading
      return
    }

    // Everything went fine, and this is similar to onFileUploadComplete
  })
})
```